# SQLiteException when setting parameter to rawQuery

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I received this crash report in Google Play Console which I can't reproduce:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2422)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2482)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:150)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1344)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5423)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement (SQLiteConnection.java)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement (SQLiteConnection.java:887)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare (SQLiteConnection.java:498)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare (SQLiteSession.java:588)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init> (SQLiteProgram.java:58)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init> (SQLiteQuery.java:37)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query (SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory (SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery (SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
  at .StatDB.getExercise (StatDB.java)
  at .ExerciseList.onCreate (ExerciseList.java)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6294)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1108)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2375)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2482)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:150)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1344)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5423)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is my `getExercise` method:

```
public List<Bean> getExercise(String sub) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = initializer.getReadableDatabase();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + sub;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        List<Bean> exeList = new ArrayList<Bean>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String code = cursor.getString(1);
            String mark = cursor.getString(2);
            exeList.add(new Bean(code, mark));
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return exeList;
    }
```

In my `ExerciseList.onCreate` :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
        subCode = i.getExtras().getString("sub");
List<Bean> exeList = statDB.getExercise(subCode);
```

I have previously mentioned "could the crash happened because `subCode` is null? However after I made the testing, I have excluded this reason. Because before the `List<Bean> exeList = statDB.getExercise(subCode);`, actually I set my `TextView` using this:

```
if (subCode.equals("bd")) {
            passTv.setText("Some Text");
        } else {
            passTv.setText("Another Text");
        }
```

So the more complete code is:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
        subCode = i.getExtras().getString("sub");
if (subCode.equals("bd")) {
                passTv.setText("Some Text");
            } else {
                passTv.setText("Another Text");
            }
List<Bean> exeList = statDB.getExercise(subCode);
```

If my `subcode` is null, my `TextView` will crash first. So the problem is suspect is my `getExercise` method, particularly the `String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + sub;`. Is it because the parameter `sub` is not passed?

Comment: what if `sub` == `"nonexistingtable"`

Comment: Because your table do not have `sub` field

Comment: In my intent.putExtra("sub", exe) , I only put my table name in extra. I'm 100% sure.

Comment: Did you ever tried to `"Hello" + null` ? This would give you `"Hellonull` You just need to check for the parameter to concatenate it or not. But please check SQL Injection !

Comment: Stack overflow folks are getting arrogant. Down voted without giving reason? My question is clearly written. I DO NOT get this crash on my own decice. Most of my users DO NOT get this crash as well. I just don't know why all of sudden, I got this crash report.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error in play console by very few random users. But it's hurting as some are rating me with a 1 star review because of this. I tried on multiple devices and can't reproduce it. Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question :

> Could the crash happened because subCode is null?

If you don't know what happen if `sub` is `null` here :

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + sub;
```

Well, it simple to check :

```
String sub = null;
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + sub;
System.out.println(sql);
```

> SELECT * FROM null

Just check for `null` values to prevent to send an incorrect query.

```
if(sub != null){
    throw new Exception("no table provided")
}
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + sub;
```

This might not be the best approach to create the query like this.
First, see about SQL Injection.
Then, what happend when your table is doesn't have 2 TEXT fields ? You should use a DAO pattern to create one class per table instead of hoping for the best.